# Can/does Firefox fire a resize event for a div that it sizes the width automatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, events, firefox, layout, html

I have a page that only contains a single div like this:

```
<div style="background-color: blue; height:30px;" onresize="alert('onresize');" ></div>
```

Per the standard, Firefox will automatically make the div's width equal to the width of its container which in this case is the entire window. But when I resize the browser window, Firefox doesn't fire a resize event on this div. I tested in IE and it does. I would say that Firefox is resizing the div's width because no scroll bars appear if I make the window smaller but then again when I look at the elements dimensions in Firebug, the width is NOT updated so it seems like mixed messages.

My main goal is to have a cross-browser event handler for the resize event on this div but I'd like to avoid using jQuery for now. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to hook into a Div's resize event, not sure if or how to make that work.

What I have made work before on both IE and FF is to hook into the window resize event and then adjust div size based on the new window size.  Usually I am trying to get a left side menu to fill the screen vertically or force a content div to fill in the remainder of the screen after a top header and/or left menu have been rendered.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but this might be another approach to take.

Comment: I'm creating a JavaScript library that attaches to one or more divs in a user's document. I need to take some action when the div is resized. The user may do this programmatically or by resizing the window, etc. I found the descrepancy when testing this.